# An img in a list item with text and animation to the text

Tags: html, css, image, animation

Okey, I'm working on a project and run in to a smal problem. I have a list that have text with an underline animation but now I want to include an img in the list. So i want to hover both the img and the text and the animation will only aply to the text. I have tried with a p element but didnt really work.

This is what I have at the moment:

```css
/*Not imortant*/
.wrapper {

  background-color: white;

  color: white;

  height: 500px;

  margin: auto;

  margin-top: 50px;

  max-width: 1024px;

  padding: 20px;

  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;

  width: 65%;

}

.wrapper h2 {

  font-size: 44px;

  margin: 0;

}

.wrapper p {

  font-size: 25px;

  font-weight: 500;

}
/*Here the important stuff happens*/

.wrapper li {

  text-align: center;

}

.wrapper a img {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100px;

}

.wrapper a p {

  color: white;

  display: inline-block;

  font-size: 25px;

  font-weight: 500;

  position: relative;

  margin: 0;

}

.wrapper a p:before {

  content: "";

  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;

  height: 2px;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  background-color: white;

  visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);

  transform: scaleX(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

}

.wrapper a p:hover:before {

  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);

  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.main {

  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);

}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper main">
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <h2>Gnestarias</h2>
    <p>Some text :)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <ul>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="arena.html">
          <p>Arena</p>
          <img src="#" alt="bild">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="athena.html">
          <p>Athena</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="eatmeat.html">
          <p>Eatmeat</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="georges.html">
          <p>Georges</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="vitavillan.html">
          <p>Vitavillan</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Note that there is an grid behind it also (toast grid to be spesific) :)

Can i do something with only css or do I have to fix it with Javascript? 
I want to be able to hover both the img and the text and the animation should only apply on the text, nothing else, and the underline should stop when the text stops

Hope you can help :)

http://johhag98.github.io/Gnesta-Pizza/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the hover trigger to the wrapping anchor

```
.wrapper a:hover p:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```css
/*Not imortant*/

.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
  width: 65%;
}
.wrapper h2 {
  font-size: 44px;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
/*Here the important stuff happens*/

.wrapper li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapper a {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper a p {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper a p:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.wrapper a:hover p:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.main {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper main">
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <h2>Gnestarias</h2>
    <p>Some text :)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <ul>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="arena.html">
          <p>Arena</p>
          <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100" alt="bild">
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you trigger the animation on hovering on the parent anchor tag?

Like this:

```
.wrapper a:hover p:before {

  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);

  transform: scaleX(1);

}
```

Demo here:

```css
/*Not imortant*/
.wrapper {

  background-color: white;

  color: white;

  height: 500px;

  margin: auto;

  margin-top: 50px;

  max-width: 1024px;

  padding: 20px;

  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;

  width: 65%;

}

.wrapper h2 {

  font-size: 44px;

  margin: 0;

}

.wrapper p {

  font-size: 25px;

  font-weight: 500;

}
/*Here the important stuff happens*/

.wrapper li {

  text-align: center;

}

.wrapper a img {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100px;

}

.wrapper a p {

  color: white;

  display: inline-block;

  font-size: 25px;

  font-weight: 500;

  position: relative;

  margin: 0;

}

.wrapper a p:before {

  content: "";

  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;

  height: 2px;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  background-color: white;

  visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);

  transform: scaleX(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;

}

.wrapper a p:hover:before {

  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);

  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.wrapper a:hover p:before {

  visibility: visible;

  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);

  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.main {

  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);

}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper main">
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <h2>Gnestarias</h2>
    <p>Some text :)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row--no-gutter">
    <ul>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="arena.html">
          <p>Arena</p>
          <img src="#" alt="bild">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="athena.html">
          <p>Athena</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="eatmeat.html">
          <p>Eatmeat</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="georges.html">
          <p>Georges</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col col--1-of-5">
        <a href="vitavillan.html">
          <p>Vitavillan</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```